# Font problems with musiXteX

Tags: musixtex

I've just installed musiXteX on TeXLive 2015, made the two links on lua scripts and try to compile this [example](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/musixtex/doc/examples/adagio.tex). `etex` run well :

> -K56CB:~/Bureau/Latex/Essais/Musique$ etex adagio.tex 
>   This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=etex)
>    restricted \write18 enabled.
>   entering extended mode
>   (./adagio.tex
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/musixtex/musixtex.tex
>   MusiXTeX(c) 1.20 <2015-12-13>
>   maxinstruments=6 max128beams=6 maxgroups=3 maxslurs=6 maxtrills=6
>   maxoctlines=6)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/musixtex/musixcpt.tex
>   MusiXComPaTible T.109 <7 July 2002>
>   ) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/musixtex/musixsty.tex
>   MusiXtextSTYle T.116 <27 February 2015>
>   ) /noautolines pass I  bar 1 bar 2 bar 3 bar 4 bar 5 [1](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/musixtex/doc/examples/adagio.tex) bar 6 bar 7 bar 8
>   bar 9 bar 10 [2] bar 11 bar 12 bar 13 bar 14 bar 15 [3] bar 16 bar 17 bar 18
>   bar 19 bar 20 [4] bar 21 bar 22 bar 23 bar 24 bar 25 [5] bar 26 bar 27 bar 28
>   bar 29 bar 30 [6] bar 31 bar 32 bar 33 bar 34 bar 35 [7] bar 36 bar 37 bar 38
>   bar 39 bar 40 [8] bar 41 bar 42 bar 43 bar 44 bar 45 [9] bar 46 bar 47 bar 48
>   bar 49 bar 50 [10] bar 51 bar 52 bar 53 bar 54 bar 55 [11] bar 56 bar 57
>   bar 58 bar 59 bar 60 [12] bar 61 bar 62 [13] )
>   Output written on adagio.dvi (13 pages, 55320 bytes).
>   Transcript written on adagio.log.

but `musixtex adagio` says :

> ...
>   kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode ljfour --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 musixspx
>   mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for musixspx.
>   mktexpk: perhaps musixspx is missing from the map file.
>   kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
>   dvips: Font musixspx not found; using cmr10
>
> dvips: Design size mismatch in font musixspx
>   dvips: Checksum mismatch in font musixspx
>   dvips: ! invalid char 160 from font musixspx
>   !! Processing of adagio.tex fails.

What is the problem ?

Comment: You compile with dvips? Did you try pdflatex for test purposes? I guess, there has been an installation fault. On https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/obsolete/fonts/musixtex/ps-type1 there is an installation instruction. Maybe you try installing them manually.

Comment: You seem to use Linux. But in MikTeX there is the Refresh FNDB button which once helped me with a similar problem. Maybe this requires a similar action.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz as I read in the manual I use three pass compilation with etex and musixtex. On the produced dvi after the third pass one can run dvips then pstopdf. It is musixtex that fails using dvips not me. I will try obsolete font option.

Comment: I don't use miktex.

Comment: TeX Live already includes `musixtex`. Why would you have to install it in addition?

Comment: Because I didn't do a full installation initially. Now I've added musixtex package.

Comment: Did you install it using `tlmgr`?

Comment: I did use tlmgr.

Comment: The example works fine for me with `etex -> musixflx -> etex`. Both the DVI looks OK (ish) and `dvipdf` produces a PDF which looks fine.

Comment: `tlmgr` does not manage dependencies. I assume that you are missing required fonts and need to install the relevant packages using `tlmgr` in addition to installing `musixtex`. That is, they may not be in the same package. Note that it is using bitmap fonts, which is not ideal, but perhaps that is all there is. (I mean, it uses bitmap fonts even when it works as it does here - not just that it is failing to use them in your case.)

Comment: OK. Type 1 are available. It just isn't using them. Don't know why. Maybe the particular example is set up a particular way. Anyway, probably you need to install `musixtex-fonts`.

Comment: @cfr ok works fine. I didn't remember that `tlmgr` doesn't take about dependencies, and didn't think about a `musixtex-fonts`. Thank you. Maybe you can right an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tlmgr` is not like a regular package manager - it does not manage dependencies and will install or remove *just what you ask* without regard to the implications for other installed packages.

In this case, installing `musixtex` is not enough because `musixtex` cannot do much without the fonts it needs to actually typeset music. The solution is, therefore, to install `musixtex-fonts` which provides a suitable complement of fonts.

When the appropriate packages from TeX Live 2015 are installed, the `adagio.tex` example file compiles with the following results:

[image: Adagio]
[image: Adagio close up]